# Avoiding detection while hacking the computer in "one step ahead"

Tags: starfield

I'm on New Game Plus x2 (NG+2) in Starfield (PC). On my first run, I completed the "One Step Ahead" Ryujin quest by going to CeltCorp, waiting until the security officer left the office area, and then hacking the computer. The hack was successful, and I went undetected.

Now I'm trying to actually complete the Ryujin quest line, so I go to CeltCorp and wait until the security officer leaves, but every time I hack the terminal I get caught and a bounty is added, and Neon Security becomes hostile. I saved right before the hack attempt and have attempted this three times, giving the security officer sufficient time (and some buffer) to clear the area -- and in all cases I get caught.

What's the trick here? How can I avoid detection while hacking the terminal in this quest?

Comment: I'm not sure: Does it work if you creep slowly and crouch to the terminal?

Comment: I think all I did was crouch down, made sure I was [Hidden], and hacked away (but I was rank 4 stealth).  I think there was a patrolling security guard in that room if I remember.  Maybe make sure they aren't facing your way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security officer has some awareness even after he's out of sight. Luckily your own spatial awareness can determine whether he can detect you.

1. Crouch.
2. Wait until the stealth status transitions from 'Detected' to 'Hidden'.
3. Hack the terminal.

This works even with no points in the stealth perks.

You don't need to crouch on your way to the terminal, simply walk to the terminal normally, wait for the security officer to leave your sight, then follow these steps.